# Jenkins pipeline environment section not executing serially

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, openshift

I am facing some issues in jenkins environment section while executing  the jenkins pipeline environment section.

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field gitScriptPath = "https://raw.github.com/Innovation/"
@Field clrInfo
@Field gitlabMem       
@Field gitSubGroupURL        
@Field clrDuration
@Field cloudProvider
@Field userSpecData
@Field slackIntMes

pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    environment {
    GITHUB_TOKEN = credentials('    GITHUB_TOKEN')
    GIT_URL = 'github.com/Innovation/exp-selling-iac.git'
    PRE_PROV = 'k8s-jobs/iac_preprovision.yaml'
    OS_PROV = 'k8s-jobs/iac_openshift.yaml'
    USER_PROV = 'k8s-jobs/rhos-user-onboard-offboard.yaml'
    ISTIO_PROV = 'k8s-jobs/iac_istio.yaml'
    KAFKA_PROV = 'k8s-jobs/iac_kafka.yaml'
    MONOLITH_PROV = 'k8s-jobs/iac_monolith.yaml'
    POST_PROV = 'k8s-jobs/iac_postprovision.yaml'
    DEVOPS_PROV = 'k8s-jobs/k8s_iac_devops.yaml'
    dummy = sh ( script: '''echo "${USER_SPEC}" > userspec.yaml''', returnStdout: true )
    NAMESPACE = sh ( script: "$JENKINS_HOME/custompath/yq r userspec.yaml Cluster.Name", returnStdout: true )
    requestor = sh ( script: "$JENKINS_HOME/custompath/yq r userspec.yaml Cluster.Users.User1.ID", returnStdout: true ).trim()
    APPOPS_ROLE = 'appops-customrole-v2'
   }
     stages {
      stage('Download - Groovy Scripts'){
```

Here we need to get the value of NAMESPACE  and requestor after executing the dummy.
But the line starting with dummy  is happening after **NAMESPACE** and **requestor** lines.
The same quote was working earlier. IF i remove requestor = or  APPOPS_ROLE = then everything will be fine. Please help to understand what is happening here. 
As i work around i can make **APPOPS_ROLE** as a parameter in jenkins by configuring the job. This has something to do with the case of the variable also. ie if i make dummy ---> DUMMY it will make a difference. 
Jenkins ver. 2.204.2  on openshift 3.11

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the ordering is undefined. Maybe the assignments are first stored in a hash table and then the hash table is enumerated, which would result in a seemingly random order.

As a workaround you could move the environment initialization into a stage, where you could use a `script` block to ensure execution order:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }

    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.dummy = sh ( script: '''echo "${USER_SPEC}" > userspec.yaml''', returnStdout: true )
                    env.NAMESPACE = sh ( script: "$JENKINS_HOME/custompath/yq r userspec.yaml Cluster.Name", returnStdout: true )
                    env.requestor = sh ( script: "$JENKINS_HOME/custompath/yq r userspec.yaml Cluster.Users.User1.ID", returnStdout: true ).trim()
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Download - Groovy Scripts'){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @zetta42. I have made APPOPS_ROLE = 'appops-customrole-v2' as a jenkins parameter ( configure job )
and the issue is solved. 
Not sure whether the workaround provided by you can be used in shell script in the pipeline.

Comment: I am more curious to understand why commands are not executed sequentially in environment section. 
Your workaround is really helpful for another issue which i was facing.
ie im not able to use the pipeline variable in shell script if its not defined with env as prefix.
I have tested your work around and variables are working in shell script as well.